# Transition on class change property

Tags: vue.js, css-animations, css-transforms, tailwind-css

I currently have a vue component that I use to select drinks to be ordered.
You can increment or decrement the amount of drinks per type.

There are 2 buttons (Increment and decrement), the decrement button needs to be hidden when the amount of ordered drinks for that type is equal to 0. This can easily be accomplished by using `:class="drink.amount > 0 ? 'visible':'invisible'"` using the tailwind classes which sets `visibility:hidden` css property. When using this method it looks like:

[image: Image showing vertically aligned buttons]

Now I tried to implement css animations (sliding the button underneath the drink block to hide it and later hide from dom). I want to implement this using the vue transition component since this is heavily used throughout the application.

Now I have the problem that the vue transition component only works with a limited amount of vue functions among which `v-if` and `v-show`. `v-if` removes the html from the dom. `v-show` sets the property `display:none` both of these functions have the effect of shifting the buttons:
[image: Image showing button missing decrement button left of center]

**I would like to known how I can use the vue transition component and get the requested aligned buttons as I got without the animation.**

```
<div v-for="drink in drinks" class="w-full flex">
    <div class="mx-auto flex">
        <transition name="transition-slide-right">
            <div class="bg-white w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center mt-12"
                 v-show="drink.amount">
                <p>-</p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <div class="bg-brand w-32 h-24 flex justify-center items-center my-8 z-30">
            <p>{{drink.name}} ({{drink.amount}})</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center mt-12">
            <p>+</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And accompanying script.

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "CreateTransaction",
        data: function() {
            return {
                drinks: [
                    {name: 'Cola', price: '1.0', amount: 1},
                    {name: 'Sinas', price: '1.0', amount: 0}
                ],
            }
        }        
    }
</script>
```

Finally the css:

```
.transition-slide-right-enter-active, .transition-slide-right-leave-active {
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.transition-slide-right-enter, .transition-slide-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

As a current workaround I removed the transition component, added the `transition-slide-right-enter-active` class and if the count == 0 I conditionally add the `transition-slide-right-enter` class. This does not hide the element but hiding it is not required since I is moved underneath the center block.

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following code

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="todo-list-example">
    <div v-for="(drink,index) in drinks" class="w-full flex">
         <transition name="transition-slide-right"><button v-show="drink.amount" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="click1(index)">-</button></transition>
       
            <a class="btn btn-success" >{{drink.name}} ({{drink.amount}})</a>
        
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="click2(index)">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.w-full{margin:10px 0px;}
   .transition-slide-right-enter-active, .transition-slide-right-leave-active {
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.transition-slide-right-enter, .transition-slide-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

</style>
<script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#todo-list-example',
 data(){
            return {
                drinks: [
                    {name: 'Cola', price: '1.0', amount: 1},
                    {name: 'Sinas', price: '1.0', amount: 1}
                ],
            }
        },
        methods:{
            click1:function(index){
                this.drinks[index].amount=this.drinks[index].amount-1;
            },
            click2:function(index){
                this.drinks[index].amount=this.drinks[index].amount+1;
            }
        }    
})
</script>
```